# Multiple level role permission in laravel

Tags: laravel

Can I use some packages like spatie for role permission in multiple level?
For example assume I have two level:

- level 1
- level 2

Each level have separate role. For example level 1 have a manager and level 2 have another manager.
How do this with spatie role permission?

Comment: I believe you would do Role1 = Level 1 Manager and Role2 = level 2 Manager and assign each permission to the roles.  Otherwise you can assign a 3 roles, level1 level2 and manager and you can check to see if a user is level1 and manager  or level2 and manager.  like $user->hasRole(['level1', 'manager']);  but you may run into issues using "manager" instead of using them as separate roles like $user->hasRole(['level_1_manager']);

Comment: What do you mean with "level" ? Is it like highest level can perform every other level's abilities or something like that? Beside of that if you want to create 2 different roles and assign them abilities, of course you can.

Comment: Level is a context or category. I have some category and subcategories and categories are dynamic and user can create some category.